# Way to get selected tab index from TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've just added TabView, which is working fine, but I unable to fetch the selected tab index out if it.
I think I've kept my code perfectly fine, not sure what's wrong.

```
struct DefaultTabbar: View {
    
    @State private var selectedItem = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedItem) {
            FirstView()
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("First Tab")
            }
            .tag(1)
            
            SecondView()
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                    Text("Second Tab")
            }
            .tag(2)
        }
        .accentColor(.orange)
        .onTapGesture {
            print("selected tab: \(self.selectedItem)")
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm receiving only 0 while switching tabs.**
selected tab: 0.
selected tab: 0.

Comment: It is changed, just use it where needed. But you may not use `.onTapGesture` on `TabView`.

Answer (score 13):

I think you have the right idea, but don't use onTapGesture, instead use OnChange():

```
struct DefaultTabbar: View {

    @State private var selectedItem = 1

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedItem) {
            FirstView()
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("First Tab")
            }
            .tag(1)

            SecondView()
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                    Text("Second Tab")
            }
            .tag(2)
        }
        .accentColor(.orange)
        .onChange(of: selectedItem) { value in print("selected tab = \(value)") }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use onAppear method for each tab. It's looks ugly but it's works.

```
struct DefaultTabbar: View {

    var lastSelectedTab = 0 {
        didSet {
            
        }
    }
    @State private var selectedItem = 1

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedItem) {
            FirstView()
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    lastSelectedTab = 0
                })
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("First Tab")
            }
            .tag(1)

            SecondView()
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    lastSelectedTab = 1
                })
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                    Text("Second Tab")
            }
            .tag(2)
        }
        .accentColor(.orange)
    }
}
```